# how can i read image from mongodb in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, carrierwave

I am adding carrierwave_mongoid to store images, i have saved images to mongo
And my data like this:

```
 { "contentType" : "image/jpeg", "length" : 512659, "chunkSize" : 4194304, "uploadDate" : ISODate("2013-01-26T00:00:00Z"), "md5" : "3d44aa8fcfba7cae34fe9a592407410b", "filename" : "uploads/deal/image/295/15a11db8e441c610330af53a77e2b136.jpg", "_id" : 5 }
```

I have a story model:

```
class Deal
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :image,        :type => String
  field :status,       :type => Integer

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

My ImageUploader code is here:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
...
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

now i want to display image from mongodb,and in the view i have

```
<%= image_tag(@deal.image.url)  %>
```

Finally Images are not display in the view and get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/uploads/deal/image/295/15a11db8e441c610330af53a77e2b136.jpg"):
```

i want to know how can i read the image through the carrierwave_mongoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionController::RoutingError` indicates that your rails application dosen't handle such requests.

Define routes to a controller to query the gridfs and send the image. Additionally, you may need to configure Nginx not to handle such requests as static files.